# How does "if" work with registers in verilog?

Tags: if-statement, verilog

a = reg[3:0].
what values of "a" return true in: "if(a)"?.
which cell of the register a does the "if" check in the previous format?.
Does it return 0 only for a=0000 or are there other values for a that make if(a)=0?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `a` is `reg [3:0]`, it evaluates to `false` inside `if` statement only when `a == 4'b0000`.

Comment: If any bit in `a` is `x` or `z`, `if (a)` will also be false.